# What open source software should I use to geocode the addresses?

Tags: open-source-gis, geocoding

Need to geocode the student addresses using the regular 5-digit zip
codes. Geocoder will give us an accurate point on the map, so in a Latitude and Longitude environment that should suffice for our specific data needs with respect to answering the question of what students belong to what congressional district. ArcGIS for Desktop
software will geocode the student addresses and get points on the map.
Then we need to create two other layers one for the representative
districts and the other for the senate districts. Then we have to use the
Spatial Join tool in the toolbox to combine the tables and give us one
attribute table that includes all of our geocode located points and what
congressional district they belong to.

So ArcGIS for desktop will be able to solve my puzzle, but is their any open GIS tool available which will solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/).

> Gisgraphy is a free, open source framework that offers the possibility
>   to do geolocalisation and geocoding via Java APIs or REST webservices.
>   Because geocoding is nothing without data, it provides an easy to use
>   importer that will automagically download and import the necessary
>   (free) data to your local database (Geonames and OpenStreetMap : 42
>   million entries).

Comment: Can the data after mapping be exported from Gisgraphy in csv format?